# How much memory (RAM) does a Bitcoin node use?

Tags: bitcoind

How much memory (RAM) does a Bitcoin node use?

I am planning on running a Bitcoin full-node on a RasPi Model A+. It only has 256MB of RAM, so I'm not sure if this will work. Most of the threads on here and bitcointalk are very old, and I'm not sure if the memory requirements are greater now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [my answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24434/minimal-system-to-run-a-full-bitcoin-node-netbook-raspberry-pi-etc/24435#24435) to the question [Minimal system to run a full Bitcoin node: Netbook? Raspberry Pi? etc](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24434/minimal-system-to-run-a-full-bitcoin-node-netbook-raspberry-pi-etc/):

I just restarted my full node and waited for it to receive a new block, which revealed that 256MB of RAM will not be enough for running a full node without [memory paging/swapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging):

[image]

so I would suggest you opt for [RasPi Model B+](http://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-b-plus/) which comes with double the RAM of its A+ predecessor or you can equip your A+ with a flash storage but you should expect degraded performance in this case.